# Webfonts - Does a user have to have the font installed on their computer

Tags: fonts, font-family, typeface

If I use a custom font face ie: Gallicide - Does a user visiting my page need to have that font also installed on their computer for it to show up? I think if this is the case I would use some sort of generic fallback font, but using the fallback makes it so that the user is not seeing what I intended to be displayed. Is there a way to combat this - if a user has to have the font installed on their computer?

Answer (score 0):

Webfonts are served from the web server, so they are able to be rendered on a client device without the client having the font installed.

That being said, not all browsers support web fonts, so you should specify a web-safe fallback font as well, just to cover your bases.

If you'd like to understand more, have a read [here](https://www.upwork.com/hiring/design/what-are-web-fonts-and-why-are-they-important/).